# How to make a Digital clock in delphi7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

I am pretty new to delphi , and would like to start with something easy .
Could someone please show me an example how to make a Digital clock that will transfer the "time" ( hour , min , sec ) to a label ? Or something like that

Comment: May I suggest your next exercise: an *analog* clock, much more fun!

Comment: Happy to see the question is not just down-voted saying the user did not do sufficient research and is not a real question etc. And I the answers also. Very nice!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Exercise 1**

Drop a `TLabel` and a `TButton` on your form.

Double-click the button, and write

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := TimeToStr(Time);
end;
```

**Exercise 2**

To get the time to update automatically, add a `TTimer` to your form, and double-click it (you can remove the button if you like). Then write

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := TimeToStr(Time);
end;
```

This code will run once a second (the default interval for a `TTimer`, which is perfect for us, so we do not need to change it).

**Exercise 3**

To make the clock more annoying, you can try this: in the interface of your form, add a private field called `FHighlight`, like this:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  Label1: TLabel;
  Timer1: TTimer;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
  FHighlight: boolean;
public
  { Public declarations }
end;
```

Now you can do

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := TimeToStr(Time);
  if FHighlight then
  begin
    Label1.Color := clWhite;
    Label1.Font.Color := clBlack;
  end
  else
  begin
    Label1.Color := clBlack;
    Label1.Font.Color := clWhite;
  end;
  FHighlight := not FHighlight;
end;
```

In order for this effect to work, you need to change one of the properties of the `TLabel` control (design-time). Change `Transparent` to `false`, using the Object Inspector, if it isn't already.

**Update (Exercise 4)**

Since Warren P thinks it is too boring with a plain `TLabel`, this is how you can achieve a 'true' seven-segment digital clock:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
type
  TDigitData = array[0..6] of boolean;
  TPhysDigit = array[0..7] of TRect;
const
  DIGIT: array[0..9] of TDigitData =
    (
      (true, true, true, true, true, true, false),
      (false, true, true, false, false, false, false),
      (true, true, false, true, true, false, true),
      (true, true, true, true, false, false, true),
      (false, true, true, false, false, true, true),
      (true, false, true, true, false, true, true),
      (true, false, true, true, true, true, true),
      (true, true, true, false, false, false, false),
      (true, true, true, true, true, true, true),
      (true, true, true, true, false, true, true)
    );
var
  PaddingW,
  PaddingH,
  UnitX,
  UnitY,
  DigitWidth,
  DigitHeight,
  BarLengthX,
  BarLengthY,
  DigitSeparation,
  FieldSeparation: integer;
  SEGMENTS: array[0..5] of TPhysDigit;
  i: Integer;

  function TranslatePhysDigit(const PhysDigit: TPhysDigit; const DX: integer; const DY: integer = 0): TPhysDigit;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to 7 do
    begin
      result[i].Left := PhysDigit[i].Left + DX;
      result[i].Right := PhysDigit[i].Right + DX;
      result[i].Top := PhysDigit[i].Top + DY;
      result[i].Bottom := PhysDigit[i].Bottom + DY;
    end;
  end;

  procedure DrawDigit(const Position, Value: integer);
  var
    i: integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to 6 do
      if DIGIT[Value, i] then
        Canvas.FillRect(SEGMENTS[Position, i]);
  end;

  procedure DrawColon(const Position: integer);
  var
    ColonRect1: TRect;
    ColonRect2: TRect;
  begin
    ColonRect1 := Rect(PaddingW + Position*UnitX, PaddingH + UnitY,
      PaddingW + (Position+1)*UnitX, PaddingH + 2*UnitY);
    ColonRect2 := Rect(PaddingW + Position*UnitX, PaddingH + 3*UnitY,
      PaddingW + (Position+1)*UnitX, PaddingH + 4*UnitY);
    Canvas.FillRect(ColonRect1);
    Canvas.FillRect(ColonRect2);
  end;

var
  t: string;

begin
  PaddingW := Width div 20;
  PaddingH := Height div 20;
  UnitX := (ClientWidth - 2*PaddingW) div 27;
  UnitY := (ClientHeight - 2*PaddingH) div 5;
  DigitWidth := 3*UnitX;
  DigitHeight := 5*UnitY;
  BarLengthX := 3*UnitX;
  BarLengthY := 3*UnitY;
  DigitSeparation := 4*UnitX;
  FieldSeparation := 6*UnitX;
  SEGMENTS[0, 0] := Rect(0, 0, DigitWidth, UnitY);
  SEGMENTS[0, 1] := Rect(DigitWidth - UnitX, 0, DigitWidth, BarLengthY);
  SEGMENTS[0, 2] := Rect(DigitWidth - UnitX, 2*UnitY, DigitWidth, DigitHeight);
  SEGMENTS[0, 3] := Rect(0, DigitHeight - UnitY, DigitWidth, DigitHeight);
  SEGMENTS[0, 4] := Rect(0, 2*UnitY, UnitX, DigitHeight);
  SEGMENTS[0, 5] := Rect(0, 0, UnitX, BarLengthY);
  SEGMENTS[0, 6] := Rect(0, 2*UnitY, DigitWidth, 3*UnitY);
  SEGMENTS[0] := TranslatePhysDigit(SEGMENTS[0], PaddingW, PaddingH);
  SEGMENTS[1] := TranslatePhysDigit(SEGMENTS[0], DigitSeparation);
  SEGMENTS[2] := TranslatePhysDigit(SEGMENTS[1], FieldSeparation);
  SEGMENTS[3] := TranslatePhysDigit(SEGMENTS[2], DigitSeparation);
  SEGMENTS[4] := TranslatePhysDigit(SEGMENTS[3], FieldSeparation);
  SEGMENTS[5] := TranslatePhysDigit(SEGMENTS[4], DigitSeparation);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(PaddingW, PaddingH, ClientWidth - PaddingW,
    ClientHeight - PaddingH));
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  t := FormatDateTime('hhnnss', Time);

  for i := 0 to 5 do
    DrawDigit(i, StrToInt(Copy(t, i+1, 1)));

  if odd(StrToInt(Copy(t, 6, 1))) then
  begin
    DrawColon(8);
    DrawColon(18);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;
```

[image: Seven-segment digital clock]

Playing with the GDI brushes:

[image: Seven-segment digital clock]

Comment: +1 If you are unlucky it could advance 2 seconds in a single update. A smaller interval could solve that.

Comment: For fun, you should at least change from using a boring old TLabel to a 7 segment "LED". :-)

Comment: Also works [as a sheet of glass](http://privat.rejbrand.se/seven-segment-glass.png).

Comment: Hm, still boring, what about analog clock with GDI animated cuckoo :-) (+1, nice work)

Comment: @TLama: I would have started on that right away, had it not been for the (sad) fact that I need to get up early tomorrow...

Comment: +1 Nice exposition of how one could get to the final goal with a few try outs.

Comment: +1 BTW, `TDigitData` could have been an Integer (representing 7 bit pattern)

Comment: @kobik: Now that you say that... of course! Too bad that you cannot enter binary numbers in Delphi source code, though...

Comment: Oh what a sweet tutorial..
we are so fortunate that we have some excellent teachers who would love to share.. thank you.. i love this tutorial..

Comment: +1,hey Self.DoubleBuffered:=true; will get rid of the flicker :)

Comment: @PresleyDias: Yes, that is true. Since I didn't see any flickering on my system, I didn't mention it, though.

Comment: @WarrenP  What LEDs??  Thats too modern for my tastes .. I prefer digital time displayed the way god intended - via Nixie tubes of course!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixie_tube

Comment: very, very nice!  Added a super small one to a TstatusBar to go with our Metro overhaul!

Answer (score 16):

Download my open source [NLDDigiLabel](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?p=221940#post221940) component from [here](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDDigiLabel), place three of them on the form, place two common labels in between as time separators, and set the background color of the form. In this example, I did all this on a frame for convenience:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,
  NLDDigiLabel;

type
  TDigitalClock = class(TFrame)
    HoursLabel: TNLDDigiLabel;
    MinsLabel: TNLDDigiLabel;
    SecsLabel: TNLDDigiLabel;
    TimeSeparator1: TLabel;
    TimeSeparator2: TLabel;
    Timer: TTimer;
    procedure TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FTime: TTime;
    procedure SetTime(Value: TTime);
  public
    property Time: TTime read FTime write SetTime;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TDigitalClock }

procedure TDigitalClock.SetTime(Value: TTime);
var
  Hours: Word;
  Mins: Word;
  Secs: Word;
  MSecs: Word;
begin
  if FTime <> Value then
  begin
    FTime := Value;
    DecodeTime(FTime, Hours, Mins, Secs, MSecs);
    HoursLabel.Value := Hours;
    MinsLabel.Value := Mins;
    SecsLabel.Value := Secs;
  end;
end;

procedure TDigitalClock.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetTime(FTime + 1/SecsPerDay);
end;

end.
```

Now, drop such a frame on your form, et voilá:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DigitalClock1.Time := Time;
end;
```

[image: DigitalClock.png]

Answer (score 1):

Here are my clock's features:

1. Time's accuracy 100%.
2. Date is also added.
3. It is easy to make and doesn't take less than 2 minutes; just create a timer and 2 labels, and write this under implementation:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Background,Clock's Settings
  form1.Caption:='Digital Clock';
  form1.Height:=260;
  form1.Width:=750;
  form1.BorderStyle:=bsToolWindow;
  form1.Color:=clbackground;

  //Label (Time,Date) Settings
  label1.Font.Size:=72;
  label1.Font.Color:=clred;
  label1.Caption:='Time';
  label1.Top:=0;
  label1.Left:=8;

  label2.Font.Size:=72;
  label2.Font.Color:=clblue;
  label2.Caption:='Date';
  label2.Top:=104;
  label2.Left:=8;
end;

//Create Clock,Calendar
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.Caption:='Time: '+timetostr(time);
  label2.Caption:='Date: '+datetostr(date);

  timer1.Interval:=1; //100% Accuracy
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as 100% `TTimer` accuracy, neither will `OnTimer` at those intervals of 1 millisecond occur. And setting the interval in the `OnTimer` event is, well... remarkable. The -1 isn't mine though.