# Create a countdown and loading bar with Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using Delphi 7 to create a program. I have a input box called CoinsEdit. When the user clicks submit, the number of seconds they will have to wait will be 

`CoinsEdit.text div 30 + 2`
. I got it to show the number of minutes and seconds they have to wait, but I want it to count down live. I also want a progress bar to go along with it. All of this will be in an Dialog Box. And the "OK" button should be disabled until the loading is completed. What I have so far:

```
procedure TForm1.onConnected;
var
  amount: string;
  user: string;
  pass: string;
begin
  amount := CoinsEdit.text;
  user := UserEdit.text;
  pass := PassEdit.text;    
  Form1.Visible := False;

  ShowMessage('Please wait for ' + Seg2Min(StrToInt(CoinsEdit.text) div 30 + 2));

  ShowMessage(user + ', ' + Trim(amount) + ' coins have been added to your ' +
    'account.');

  Form1.Visible := True;
  UserEdit.Text := '';
  PassEdit.Text := '';
  CoinsEdit.Text := '';
end;
```

Seg2Min is a function which converts seconds into minutes and seconds. This is the function:

```
Min := Seg div 60;
Rest := Seg - (Min*60);
if Min = 0 then
  Seg2Min:= FormatFloat('0', Rest) + ' seconds'
else
  Seg2Min:= FormatFloat('0', Min) + ' minutes and ' + FormatFloat('0', Rest) + 
    ' seconds';
```

How do I use a `TTimer` and use it for a countdown?

Comment: So, you want from us to finish your job. Or what you have trouble with ? What is your question ?

Comment: How do I use a TTimer and use it for a countdown?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to make a Digital clock in delphi7?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9487451/576719).

Comment: That only shows the current time, I need mine to count down from a certain amount of minutes/seconds.

Comment: Instead of calling TimeToStr(Time) in the timer event, insert your downcount function and set the label to the Seg2Min value.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so what i did to tackle this problem is:

1.Create 2 forms.(frmLogin,frmDialog)

2.If the submit button is clicked i show the 2nd form "frmDialog"

3.Then i have a timer that updates the progress bar.

The piece of code you are interested in is :

```
private
  { Private declarations }
    TimeRemaining,startvalue : Integer;
public
  { Public declarations }
end;


procedure TfrmDialog.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TimeRemaining:=StrToInt(frmLogin.edtCoins.text) div 30 + 2;
  startvalue:=TimeRemaining;
end;

procedure TfrmDialog.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lblProgress.Caption:='Please wait for ' + IntToStr(TimeRemaining);
  TimeRemaining:=TimeRemaining-1;
  ProgressBar1.Max:= startvalue * 200;
  ProgressBar1.StepBy(200);
  if TimeRemaining < 0 then
    begin
    btnOk.Enabled:=true;
    lblProgress.Hide;
  end;
end;
```

You will just have to fill in the correct math.
But i think you get the idea if you dont understand or want more help just leave a comment.

Comment: I would set the timer property to 500 or 1000.

Comment: True. The comment was more for OP, because I believe that it's an important detail.